# Writing binary unsigned char to file gives incorrect output c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I just want to write 0x80 to a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char c;
    c = 128;
    ofstream of("f.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    of.write((char *) &c, sizeof(c));
    of.close();
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
$ od -tx1 f.bin
0000000 ef bf bd
0000003
```

What am I not understanding? reinterpret_cast gives the same output.

Comment: Are you sure `f.bin` is the right file? Becuase, it seems to be working on my local machine with reading/writing and with `od` as well; and, online too. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Eqh2bw). The command `$ od -t x1 test.bin` results in `80`.

Comment: Please add error checking before and after your `write` operation and verify that you are running the program from the same working directory in which the file is located afterwards.

Comment: I was using this online compiler (and downloading the file) https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler. I compiled with g++ on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: @Ralph: It's working now?

Comment: @Azeem. Yes, only on my machine. I did not investigate why the onlinegdb.com compiler was giving false output.

Comment: @Ralph: It's working fine over [there](https://onlinegdb.com/BygZsT8wI).